# Xamarin Forms-Android: How to center align,change font size,font family of text in Navigationbar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to center align text in navigationbar for Xamarin form-Android. Also would like to change the font size and font family. I tried https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59722/toolbar-title-set-center-align but not working for PCL.

Anyone got a solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve the fontsize and font by creating a custom renderer for navigation page. For the center align I'm not sure how to achieve that since you can only call the toolbar and textbox is inside the toolbar (try giving padding maybe?).

For fontsize / font on IOS:

```
public class CustomNavigationBarRenderer : NavigationRenderer
{
 public override void ViewDidLoad()
 {
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    this.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes=new UIStringAttributes()
    {
        Font = UIFont.FromName("font",fontsize)
    };

 }
}
```

Comment: My issue is for android, for iOS by default text is center aligned

Comment: Which font do you want to use ? a custom font or ? For the text align in navigation, I wasted a lot of time into that, it's hardly possible, you could perhaps aquire the textbox by using getchildren on the navigation bar. The reason they made it not possible to center is to remain the 'native' look of the OS

Comment: I am able to align text to center but it change when having a back button. Yes i want to use custom font. Then how about font size

Comment: http://www.devprotocol.com/change-the-font-type-of-a-navigationpage-title-in-xamarin-forms/ this is a good link for custom font renderer. For your backbutton problem, are you using an eventhandler perhaps? it is possible that the event doesn't get called anymore when pressing the backbutton. Perhaps put your code in your post?

Comment: issue happens when we navigation from one page to another. Thanks for the link for custom font

Comment: So if understand you correctly, it's not only the backbutton that breaks the center but also when they just navigate to a other page with a bar?